# upload file onClick without pressing button

Tags: javascript, forms, upload

I'm using js to upload files to the server using this

```
<form name="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="float:left;">
   <input id="fileToUpload" type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="input">
   <button class="button" id="buttonUpload" onClick="return ajaxFileUpload();">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Instead of clicking the "Upload" button can I just return `ajaxFileUpload();` after I browsed for a file and it's sent in the input?

I tried

```
<form name="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="float:left;">
    <input id="fileToUpload" type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="input" onClick="return ajaxFileUpload();">
</form>
```

but it returns `ajaxFileUpload();` immediately when I click the file input. Is there a way to return it only after it has some input in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using the onChange event instead.